# Why can’t I get this simple CSS transition to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn and practice CSS transitions but I don't know why I can't get this `div class=text` transition to work.

```js
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle')
const showCase = document.querySelector('.showcase')
const text = document.querySelector('.text')

menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menuToggle.classList.toggle('active')
  showCase.classList.toggle('active')
  text.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
.text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  transition-duration: 0.9s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.text.active {
  left: 950px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h2>This</h2>
  <h3>Transition</h3>
  <p>
    Lorem
  </p>
  <a href="#">Hover</a>
</div>
```

Here is the codepen so see the full picture
https://codepen.io/Code_Blues/pen/vYgGeXQ

I'm trying to transition the `div class=text` easing to the right when the `menu toggle` is clicked but it doesn’t seem to work.

Can anyone help and tell me what I seem to be doing wrong? I would be really grateful.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `"TypeError: menuToggle is null"` please fix your snippet code.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for you is using transform: translate functions.

For example, Try something like that instead you current .text.active class.

.text.active{
transform: translateX(400px)
}

Comment: That worked great! thank you, im going to practice and learn more about transform from now on too I guess.  But do you know the probable reasons why using transition didn't work this time? Again thanks!

Comment: In your case, it didn't work because you didn't have a property left in the main class .text. So, de transiton none to 950px doesn't work.
You can use the transform class that I wrote or just define an initial value for the left property in the text class.

Comment: Yeah now I know where I screwed up, I appreaciate you for taking the time to even explain that to me really.

Answer (score 0):

#### Just simply add `left: 100px;` to `.text`.

```
. . .

.text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  transition-duration: 0.9s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  left: 100px;
}

.text.active {
  left: 950px;
}

. . .
```

> [Check it in action on codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/JjEXpOv)

---

You need to provide `.text` with an initial position. Now if you will add `left: 0;` it will start from the complete start of the window.

And overall you have added a `100px` `padding` to the `.showcase` `section`. So we will add add `left: 100px;` to make the text align with other elements.

---

#### With `left: 0;`:

[image]

#### With `left: 100px;`:

[image]

Comment: Yeah wow thank you that worked! what was the reason why I had to add `left:100px` to `.text`? , I'm guessing it has something to do with the div's positioning?

Comment: @CodeBlues I added some explanation. If you did not understand anything you can tell me. It was 04:30 AM in the morning... And I was sleepy so did not add an explanation 

Answer (score 0):

You can define different values for transition properties like height.

```
.text{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  height: 300px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  
}

.text.active{
  height: 10px;
  left:950px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks now I know my mistake of not putting the starting property transition, really appreciate you for taking the time to answer.